# UIView animation, condition of when view reached point x

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, navigationbar

In my current animation, I'm moving an UIView from the bottom to the top. The view is added to the navigation controller's view so it will show on top of the navigation bar.

A simplified version of the animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { self.bar.frame.origin.y = 0 }
```

In this animation, the view will eventually reach the navigation bar. Is it possible to somehow get this condition and do something with the navigation bar?

Comment: Are you wanting to know when the animation is completed? I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If your 'condition' is the final state of the animation, then just use `+ animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` instead and do the work in the `completion` block. If not, it's a little more complicated but some animation frameworks (like facebook's `pop`) simplify things a bit by providing mechanisms for callbacks while the animation is running.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant during the animation. I think I'll take a look at face book's pop framework. Thanks!